# How to compile an assembly from source code

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have just downloaded an extended version of the Windows Phone ToolKit from this [link](https://github.com/kvervo/HorizontalLoopingSelector/tree/NoDo),
and I don't know how to compile the source code. I used NutGet to install WPToolKit but this one here can't be installed by it. 
But anyway I would love to learn how to compile an assembly from source code.
PS: I am still a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: There's a `HorizontalLoopingSelectorSample.sln` solution file in the page you linked.  That's the file you will want to open on your computer, from the root Windows Phone Toolkit folder.

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You should also have downloaded and installed the Windows Phone 7 SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Comment: I have already installed, how can use it for a horizontal looping selector

Comment: I have opened the sln file, can't I convert the entire project into a dll file?